# Integrate IP cameras to a standalone PC as a security system

Tags: ip

I want to integrate quite a few [IP Surveillance cameras](http://www.tradexguru.com/wholesale-cctv-security/wholesale-nvr-ip-internet-monitoring-cameras-internet-protocol/800-tvl-cctv-camera-security-surveillance-outdoor-night-vision-4-ir-led-array-798.html) to a dedicated PC (one that is unused at our office), I have looked at purchasing a NVR but I want to add about 16 overall and not many NVRs are capable to handle this amount if cameras.
Has anyone tried to setup a monitoring unit on a PC with IP cameras, did you use any specific software? How many HDD did you use?
Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build an effective IP securitysystem you will need the followings:

#### 1. Broadband Internet connection:

Stable Internet connection is essentially needed.

#### 2. One or more IP camera(s):

According to the specification of the camera you have mentioned, the IP camera you want to use is **ONVIF-compliant**.

(*Quoting from **onvif.org**, ONVIF, that is Open Network Video Interface Forum, is an IP-based security standard: it is an open industry forum for the development of a global standard for the interface of IP-based physical security products. The ONVIF specification defines a common protocol for the exchange of information between network video devices including automatic device discovery, video streaming and intelligence metadata.*)

The ONVIF standard ensures that there are interoperable products on the market, no matter what happens to individual companies. It increases flexibility and gives greater freedom of choices in case of developing an existing or creating a new surveillance system. Integrating a new equipment into the system takes only a little time.

#### 3. PC:

In order to use your **IP cameras** with your **PC** you need to **connect both of them to the same network**. The best way to get the most out of your cameras if you install a **camera viewer application** or an **IP camera device manager** on your PC. By using such a device manager (or a simple camera viewer application) you can display the image of your cameras on your dedicated PC - even the image of multiple cameras simultaneously. You can find many device managers on the market that can be used to connect certain amount of cameras into one security system (this capacity depends on the product).

After connecting the cameras to your system, due to the ONVIF specification, you can control your surveillance system with the help of such useful functionalities as automated device discovery, video analytics, web-broadcasting, motion detection, PTZ control, etc.

#### NVRs vs. video recorder software

If you can not find any NVR on the market that is able to handle as many IP cameras as you want to use, a **video recorder application** can solve your problem. If you are not averse to C# development, you can take a look at this Codeproject article ([How to Create a Video Recording Application (NVR/DVR software) for an ONVIF IP Camera using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826531/How-to-Create-a-Video-Recording-Application-NVR-DV)) that demonstrates step-by-step how to implement a video recorder application that can be used on your PC and that is able to record and save camera videos without using any dedicated device. This way **you can avoid using any NVR or DVR**.

I hope I helped you to get started!